# perl: how to save only editted changes from editted file (withou deleting it)?

Tags: regex, shell, perl

I edit a file from STDIN:
`$ perl -wlne 'if ((/start here/ .. /end here/)&&(/line to change/)) { print  s/match/CHANGE/r }' somefile.txt`

I have added `-i` option, but that left only changes in file (the one line), everything else was removed. So how to save only the change from the regex in a `line to change` but not deleting everything else?

Comment: Re "*How can I print changes to the current editing file?*", That's what you said you did, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's needed :

```
perl -wlpe 's/match/CHANGE/
              if (/start here/ .. /end here/)
                  && /line to change/' somefile.txt
```

`-p` takes care of print.

Once you are happy with the result, you can add `-i` for in-place edit.

Comment: The syntax is `SIMPLE_STATEMENT if EXPR;`, not `SIMPLE_STATEMENT if ( EXPR );`. Fixed. Also removed the extraneous block you added.